# Objective C how to block user interaction with my current location pin on map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkannotationview, mapkit

How can I block user interaction with the my current location pin? I have problem like this: I have many pins on my map and if they are close and they are around "my current location" pin, that pin takes the click event I wan to block it. i don't want the bubble "Current Location" to be shown.
I know it is something with  *pinView.canShowCallout = NO; but how do I know what pin is my location??
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should give you what you need..

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
    view.canShowCallout=NO;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works.. :)

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't work because you need to select it at least one to work it out, but thanks anyway it helped very much for the search starting point :)
I did it with this code:

```
    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    for(int i = 0; i< [views count]; i++)
    {
        if([[[[views objectAtIndex:i] class] description] isEqualToString:@"MKUserLocationView"])
        {
            ((MKAnnotationView*)[views objectAtIndex:i]).canShowCallout = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

you must find the view and them apply it.

also you need to put this:

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        [mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation].canShowCallout = NO;
        return [mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];

    }
```

in :- `(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation`

Comment: I would try to limit it to the mapView:viewForAnnotation method as I'm pretty sure the for loop is superfluous.

Comment: in viewForAnnotation you're supposed to return nil, so you don't really have an object to do this on there.